# How to use Java Comparator Interface to sort an Object list with reference to another list that has ids

Tags: java, list, comparator

I have an Entity called `ArtWork` which has various fields.

For some functionality, I query MySql for a list of artworks - `List<ArtWork> artworks`.
I also have another `List` of type `Long` - `List<Long> artworkIds`.

The `'artworks'` list will have objects that belong to any of the ids in the `'artworksIds'` list but not in the order as in the `'artworkIds'`.

Hence I want to sort the List `'artworks'` by id with reference to the order of the ids present in the List `'artworkIds'`.

would like to use `Comparator` to achieve this

Thanks

Comment: I suggest to implement a comparator or create a DTO in wich you put artworks and the Id.

Comment: Thanks Riadh, can you share a snippet on how to use comparator/ create a DTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MYComparator implements Comparator<Artwork> {
  List<Long> artworkIds;
  MYComparator (List<Long> artworkIds) {
   this.artworkIds = artworkIds;
 }
 @Override
 public int compare(Artwork o1, Artwork o2) {
   int index1= artworkIds.indexOf(o1.getId());
   int index2 = artworkIds.indexOf(o2.getId());
   return (i1 < i2) ? -1 : ((i1 > i2) ? 1 : 0) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Riadh, Awesome.. That was a Cake Walk...!

Comment: Don't forget to change the constructor name *RefListComparator* to *MYComparator* ...

Comment: @DirkNM - Thanks, I have done that and got it working..!

Comment: @KaushikShanmugamNagaraj  You do realize that each call to `indexOf` takes O(n) (at least for ArrayList and LinkedList implementations of List). This means the entire sort algorithm will take O(n^2log(n)) instead of O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

I would store the Artwork instances in a Map where the key is the artworkID.
Then I would iterate over the list of artworkIDs and fetch the Artworks from the Map by their ID, in the required order.

If you insist on the Comparator solution (which I don't recommend), you can do something like this :

```
public int compare(ArtWork o1, ArtWork o2) {

    int i1 = listOfIDs.indexOf(o1.getID());
    int i2 = listOfIDs.indexOf(o2.getID());
    return (i1 < i2) ? -1 : ((i1 > i2) ? 1 : 0) ;
}
```

You should add handling of the case where an artwork ID is not found in the list of IDs.

Note that each call to **indexOf** makes a linear search of your list of IDs, which makes this solution **very bad** in terms of performance :

Each call to `indexOf` takes `O(n)` (at least for `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` implementations of `List`). This means the entire sort algorithm will take `O(n^2log(n))` instead of `O(n log(n))`.

On the other hand, creating the map as I suggested and iterating once over the list of IDs would take `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks Eran, but for efficiency purpose can we do it with the Comparator Interface?

Comment: @KaushikShanmugamNagaraj I'm not sure if it would be more efficient with a Comparator. You can do it with a comparator if your comparator instance has access to the list of IDs. Then in compare(o1,o2), you search whether o1.getID() comes before o2.getID() in the list of IDs.

Comment: I have the access to the ID list from my Comparator instance. Can you show me how to my idList along with the compare() method in a snippet so that it helps me out?

Comment: @KaushikShanmugamNagaraj Edited my answer, but I still don't recommend taking this approach.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Not sure if thats the perfect one. Will keep this thread active

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that helps you, but maybe there are more efficient algorithms to do this:

```
public static class RefListComparator implements Comparator<Artwork> {

  List<Long> reflist;

  RefListComparator(List<Long> reflist) {
    this.reflist = reflist;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(Artwork o1, Artwork o2) {
    for (long refid : reflist) {
      if (o1.id == refid) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (o2.id == refid) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Comparator for sorting using id's as follows

```
public class ArtWorksIdComparator implements Comparator<ArtWork>{

    public int compare(ArtWork a1, ArtWork a2) {

        return (a1.getId() < a2.getId() ) ? -1: (a1.getId() > a2.getId() ) ? 1:0 ;
    }

}
```

For understanding the difference between Comparator and Comparable, you can check [this post in java geeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/difference-between-comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html)
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.

```
Collections.sort(artworks, new Comparator<ArtWork>() {
    public int compare(ArtWork left, ArtWork, right) {
        return Integer.compare(artworkIds.indexOf(left.getId()), listA.indexOf(left.getId()));
            }
 });
```